# How do you colour a card containing a list without colouring outside the card?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a leaderboard. To indicate positions 1-3 are special, I chose to colour the background of a listview. My approach to this was to use a `listview.separated()` with a builder that returns a coloured container. However, it doesn't look nice because the colour overflows past the card's rounded borders.

[image: Screenshot of the UI]

My current code:

```dart
Card(
  child: Container(
    child: ListView.separated(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          color: switch (index) {
            0 => const Color(0xfffce269),
            1 => const Color(0xffc1c8d1),
            2 => const Color(0xffe69b4b),
            _ => const Color(0xfff7f2f9),
          },
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Text("${index + 1}: Placeholder"),
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Divider(thickness: 1, height: 1);
      },
      itemCount: 15,
    ),
  ),
)
```

How do you make the container not fill past the card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Clip.hardEdge` in `Card` property.

```
Card(
   clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge, // <<<<< Here
   child: Container(
     child: ListView.separated(
        ...
     )
   )
)
```